# Karate doesn't recognize dashes

Tags: karate

I wrote a simple mock that checks if a specific header exists then return a specif response based on that, but karate doesn't understand dashes(-) in my headers for an example Client-ID gives an error of `ReferenceError: "ID" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1` but header Accept work fine. i'm passing this header through postman.

[image]

and this how the code looks

```js
* def fun = function(){ var test = requestHeaders; for(i in test) if(test.Client-ID) return true}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have characters like `-` part of the JSON key, you need to use quotes.

```
* def foo = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
* match foo['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
```

Also try if this works for you, it may be simpler:

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/v1/headers') && karate.get("requestHeaders['Client-ID']")
```

And in case you are testing a value, `headerContains()` can be used: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#headercontains